# No Thunderbolt Support - Thinkpad T480s on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: thinkpad, thunderbolt

No Thunderbolt support on the latest Ubuntu LTS, running on a Thinkpad T480s. I have the `bolt` package installed (it was installed by default) and installed `thunderbolt-tools`. Still get this message in settings after restarting: **No Thunderbolt Support. Thunderbolt security level could not be determined.**